# How to use the plugin jquery.cookie?

Tags: cookies, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to set a cookie in my local machine using the jquery.cookie plugin. I already downloaded the jquery files that are needed and create a html file with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js "></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js "></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $.cookie('name','value');
     });
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the cookie it's not set in Google Chrome. What is wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this: First the html file have to be open in the server. I already have apache configured so I open the file with the localhost. Then the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../javaframeworks/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../javaframeworks/jquery-cookie/src/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/shadowbox.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript">
      if ($.cookie('backdrop')==null){
          $(document).ready(function(){
             $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':' 0.85'}, 250, "linear");
             $('.box').animate({'opacity':' 1.00'}, 250, "linear");
             $('.backdrop , .box').css('display', 'block');
             $('.close').click(function(){
                 close_box();
             });
             $('.backdrop').click( function(){
                 close_box();

             });  

          });
          $.cookie('backdrop','1');
       }
       function close_box(){
          $('backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'},250, 'linear',function(){
                $('.backdrop , .box').css('display', 'none');
          });
        }  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="backdrop"></div>
     <div class="box">
         <div class="close"><img src="../img/big_close.png"></div>
         <div class="contentbox">
             <img src="../img/warning.jpg" id="aviso">
             <h4 id="msg"> Está página está em fase de desenvolvimento</h4>
         </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The goal of this code is to show a div with a message in front of the page content and put an opact background. But only the first time the user open the page.